# How to mix text and formulas in a single cell in the Wolfram Cloud Notebook?

Tags: notebooks, cells, wolfram-cloud

How to [mix text and formulas in a single cell](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MixingTextAndFormulas.html) in the Wolfram Cloud Notebook?

The shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>(</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>(</kbd> don't work (they probably are intercepted by the browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Answer written at the time of `$CloudVersion`: 1.53.0.1 (November 5, 2019)*

---

My guess is that interactive work with inline cells is not supported in the web browser front end yet.

You can see that inline cells are known and rendered well:

```
CellPrint @ TextCell[
   Row[{"Test ",Defer@Integrate[x^2,{x,0,1}]}],
   "Section"
]
```

but once this cell is printed you can't edit or even move selection inside the Input inline cell.

So in order to create those cells you can use a `CellPrint @ cell` approach.

At the end the most convenient way is probably to develop your notebook on desktop Mathematica and upload to the Cloud.

Comment: Thank you, @Kuba. _"the most convenient way is probably to develop your notebook on desktop Mathematica and upload to the Cloud"_ this would be the smarter move. Unfortunately, as you may have guessed, if I use the Cloud version, this is mostly because of the free tier. Even if there are relatively inexpensive plans, they are still out of my budget for now ;)

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I understand. I just added an example that is more straightforward to use. You can write the content in input form rather than using box-language. You can replace Section with Text style if you want too.

Comment: Cool. I will study that in depth.

Answer (score 3):

It's correct that we don't have a full-blown typesetting editor in the [Wolfram Cloud](https://www.wolframcloud.com/) yet. That's one of our longer-term projects.

For now, you could use the special "Inline InputForm-based input" we added recently: Press `Ctrl+Shift+1` and you get an input field where you can type an expression in [InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html) (e.g. `x/y^2`) which will turn into its typeset equivalent once you press `Enter`. You can go back to edit mode by clicking it. This will be added to the "Insert" menu soon so it's easier to discover.

Other alternatives that might suit you in certain cases:

- You can use "Evaluate in Place" (`Cmd+Enter` on Mac / `Ctrl+Enter` on Windows) if you want to *evaluate* something inline.
- You can convert a *whole* cell from `InputForm` to `StandardForm` (`Ctrl+Shift+N` on Mac / `Ctrl+Alt+N` on Windows); `Ctrl+Shift+I` / `Ctrl+Alt+I` to go back to `InputForm`.
- You can take some (typeset) output and copy it into another cell, e.g. by clicking it (if you get the click-to-copy overlay) or by selecting the cell bracket and pressing `Cmd+C` / `Ctrl+C` and then pressing `Cmd+V` / `Ctrl+V` while the cursor is inside the other cell.

I described some of these things in greater detail in the [blog post about 1.50 and 1.51](https://blog.wolfram.com/2019/08/29/wolfram-cloud-150-151-major-new-releases-bring-cloud-another-step-closer-to-the-desktop/).

Comment: Cool! Thank for <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+1</kbd>. I didn't know that one. Concerning the other alternatives you mention: while new to Mathematica, I already use them--so they should already be mentioned in the docs somewhere. They are available in the cog menu anyway--but I can't remember where I read about the keyboard shortcuts.  Concerning <kbd>ctrl-v</kbd>, I noticed though, while pasting certain objects, I sometimes end up with a small pink/red rectangle instead of the expected object. I will try to reproduce that and post a question here if you want.

Comment: Yeah, please let me know if you run into such an issue, ideally with steps to reproduce.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211337/the-wolfram-cloud-notebook-does-not-copy-cells-properly for an issue with cell pasting in 1.53.0.1

Comment: August 2020, still no progress on that?