# Using the Control key to edit notebooks on wolframcloud

Tags: wolfram-cloud, keyboard

Using the notebooks on mathematica.wolframcloud.com in the browser is very convenient, but I can't figure how to type fractions, powers, etc using the "Control" key as the key seems to be captured by the webpage.

Comment: Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/211318/1871

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no support for 2D style input yet. However, after you type it in 1D, you can click the gear icon next to the cell bracket and "convert to traditional form" like this:

[image]

Which converts it to look like this:

[image]