# How to create a denominator for division in Wolfram Cloud?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, mathematica-online

How to create a denominator for division, or other math objects like superscript for exponent, in Wolfram Cloud? In Mathematica you have the typesetting/characters window, or you can use Ctrl+/ for example. In Cloud this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/211318/1871 To be more specific, I think Ctrl + Shift + 1 and type something like a/b is the best thing we can do at the moment.